# Implementing a C++ (pure) interface using plain C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, vtable

Given a pure C++ class:

```
class ICppA {
public:
    virtual ~ICppA() {}
    virtual double add(double v) = 0;
    virtual double sub(double v) = 0;
    virtual double get() = 0;
};
```

Are there ways to create implementations of this interface in plain C in clang and gcc?

I understand the C++ standard does not cover the `vtable` structure, and I understand this may not be a good idea. I am looking for compiler specific, probably non-portable solutions.

#### Example for MSVC

The following works for MSVC, (but is not portable):

```
typedef struct CA CA;

// The plain C vtable
struct CA_VTable {
    void (*dtor)(CA*);
    double (*add)(CA*, double v);
    double (*sub)(CA*, double v);
    double (*get)(CA*);
};

// The plain C implementation
struct CA {
    CA_VTable* _vtable;
    double total;
};

void CA_DTor(CA*) {}
double CA_Add(CA* o, double v) { return (o->total += v); }
double CA_Sub(CA* o, double v) { return (o->total -= v); }
double CA_Get(CA* o) { return o->total; }

// Create a static vtable that all instances can use
static CA_VTable _CA_VTable = {
    CA_DTor,
    CA_Add,
    CA_Sub,
    CA_Get
};

void CA_CTor(CA* ca) { ca->_vtable = &_CA_VTable; ca->total = 0; }
```

```
void testA(ICppA* a)
{
    std::cout << "initial value: " << a->get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "add 5: " << a->add(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sub 2: " << a->sub(2) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    CA ca;
    CA_CTor(&ca);
    testA((ICppA*)&ca);
    CA_DTor(&ca);
    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]
It seems like the code above will work on clang and gcc if the `vtable` contains an extra pointer before the first method, i.e.

```
// The plain C vtable
struct CA_VTable {
    void* unknown;
    void (*dtor)(CA* self);
    double (*add)(CA* self, double v);
    double (*sub)(CA* self, double v);
    double (*get)(CA* self);
};

[...]

// Create a static vtable that all instances can use
static CA_VTable _CA_VTable = {
    nullptr,
    CA_DTor,
    CA_Add,
    CA_Sub,
    CA_Get
};
```

(I am still reading to figure out what that `unknown` pointer is and if the solution then becomes reliable)

Comment: You're going to have to look up how each platform's C++ ABI works and copy that. It's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: What's the point of doing that? Sounds like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: As you answered it yourself, this cannot be done in portable code. You can only emulate a specific compiler.

Comment: Your example code may well work for gcc and clang too.  You'd have to test it - I doubt if this is documented anywhere. But a key difference with MSVC  is that Microsoft _do_ guarantee that code like this is valid, so you are on much safer ground.

Comment: OK, reading @NicolBolas' comment, maybe gcc and clang _do_ document their ABI, and maybe it's guaranteed not to change.  As he says, you'd have to check.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The answer will likely be different on each ABI - and I know asking for non-portable implementations is taboo, but I'm interested in the answer for the following reasons: (1) I have a strict C library that needs to interact with a C++ DLL asking for an implementation; (2) I'd be interested to understand how each of gcc/clang's `vtable` work through this example (purely academic); and (3) if we can manually/dynamically construct vtables, it opens up interesting use cases where implementations can change or by dynamically created and I'd like to explore these.

Comment: Also to confirm (@PaulSanders) - this does compile on clang and gcc, but it either returns an incorrect result (it substracted 5 twice) or ends up segfaulting. I will continue reading about their respective ABI and see if I can figure out the answer on own if nobody knows.

Comment: @GaspardP (1): of course you already do know that, but the simplest way is to create a wrapper library written in C++ with `extern "C"` calls. I believe it is much simpler than manual vtables constructing.

Comment: The itanium ABI has an RTTI pointer at the beginning. I think ypu might have RTTI disabled which sets it to 0. See https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable